# Hermitian Matrix Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, hermitian-matrices

If we have {$A_{ij}\}_{n*n}$ a Hermitian matrix. v=($v_1,v_2..v_n$), w=($w_1,w_2...w_n$) are two complex vectors. Then how can I show the inequality

|$\sum_{i,j=1}^nA_{ij}v_i\overline{w_j}$|$\leq \sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^nA_{ij}v_i\overline{v_j}} \sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^nA_{ij}w_i\overline{w_j}}$

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 2):

This is the [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) (with a square root taken on both sides).

Comment: Could you say it more specific? If I am supposed to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in vector forms. Would you mind pointing out which two vectors we are dealing with?

Comment: We also require $A$ is positive-definite, right?

Comment: @DavidRaveh I wrote this answer a long time ago, but presumably o.p. must have meant as much. After all, if $A$ isn't at least positive semi-definite then the arguments of the radicals need not be nonnegative.

Comment: @TravisWillse Thought so. Decided to add an answer to address this point.

Answer (score 1):

I shall expand on @TravisWillse answer. It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Complex_coordinate_space) that given a **positive-definite, Hermitian** matrix $A$, one can define an inner product
$$\langle x|y\rangle_A=x^*Ay=\sum_{i,j=1}^n x_i^* A_{ij}y_j.$$
The [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), for any valid inner product, states
$$|\langle x|y\rangle|^2\leq \langle x|x\rangle\cdot\langle y|y\rangle.$$
Using our inner product and taking square-root gives the desired result.